# Is it possible to run a screensaver on an Android device?

Tags: screen

I want to run a screen saver when my phone is in sleep mode. Currently, if my phone says idle for a bit it fades to a black screen. Instead I want to display some images as screen saver. Is this possible?

Comment: This would be a great way to rapidly discharge your battery.  Do you want to be charging it all day?

Comment: "Screen saver" would be a real misnomer in this case.

Answer (score 7):

> I want to run a screen saver when phone is in sleep mode.

When the phone is in sleep mode, the screen is off.

> When we stay idle some time a black screen comes.

This is built into Android.

> At that time I want to display some images as screen saver.

I repeat, when the phone is in sleep mode, the screen is off.

> Is this possible?

You cannot have the screen on and the device in sleep mode.

Answer (score 6):

ICS (Android 4.0) includes the capability for "Screen Candy" that is special screens or animations that only present themselves when the phone is idle and plugged in or docked.  By default, this is a hidden (disabled in most stock roms, I'd wager) feature called "Android Dreams" but enabled in most custom roms (such as AOKP or Codename Android).

http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/11/30/another-ics-easter-egg-weird-star-wars-like-light-speed-launcher-found-hidden-in-the-depths-of-ice-cream-sandwich/

Answer (score 3):

A Screen Saver is meant to prevent image burn in on your monitors for when you leave the screen on for too long. Since Android phones automatically turn screens off after a certain (set) duration of non-use, then there is no need for a screen saver. (Tangent: there really isn't a need for screen saver on desktop monitors either, it's better power conservation wise to just let them automatically turn off after X period of time of non-use.)

But here is where Live Wallpapers come in play.  They give you something like a Screen Saver (oh! pretty animations/graphics!), but they are only in use when you are staring at your phone's home screen.  They still consume more battery than a static wallpaper, but some people prefer their phone to "look cool" than to save power. :)

Answer (score 1):

Refer to Brandorf, "Screen Candy" is now officially named as "**Daydream**".

When Daydream is on, your tablet displays photos, colors, and more while it is charging or docked.

[Set up Daydream] : http://support.google.com/nexus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2818748

Caution: Only for Android **4.2** and higher.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your battery usage charts and you'll probably find that your display uses more of your battery than all other types of consumption by your phone combined.

Is this just for aesthetic purposes?  I think this would get annoying pretty fast unless you only keep your phone tethered, in which case, get a desktop :)